# Simple c++ program with mysql DataBase connection using Eclipse on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse, ubuntu

So, the title says it all.
How can i create a simple c++ application on ubuntu and connect it to a simple mysql DataBase?
Is there a good link or description that I can go with ?

I want to make a simple web service for now and then make it more complex to fit my needs and embbed my c++ code that I already got.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your problem ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api.html
and 
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/MySQL
[btw, 4 times simple sounds like big trouble :)]

Comment: I do now know if an ODBC connector is a must for the connection between c++ and an sql DB. If it is, can I find a good guide for that? In simple words, I do not know how to connect c++ application with a simple sql database.

Comment: Sql-C-Api (the first link I provided). There is no need for odbc, when you only want to connect to mysql. If you want to be independent from your Backend, then you should have a look at odbc.

Comment: http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/mysql-capi-tutorial.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Program communicating with MySQL Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257552/c-program-communicating-with-mysql-database)